# How to fix a corrupted LibreOffice spreadsheet

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, spreadsheet

I have a substantial multi-sheet LibreOffice worksheet that seems to be throwing a lot of errors in LibreOffice, including crashes.

Any idea of how to get it to work as expected?

I'm thinking perhaps an export followed by an import, but I'm concerned I will lose some of my work.  The worksheet uses many different features, including conditional formatting, hidden rows, range names, et al.

Answer (score 3):

ODT files like Calc ods are container formats. They are in fact zip files that you can unzip. Copy the file, change the extension from ods to zip, unzip it. Inside should be a folder which can hold images, and an XML file (content.xml) that has the actual data in it. You'll find some other files that you can ignore. You could analyse the XML in an XML editor. The edited file can be put back, zipped, renamed to ods, and see if that works.

I don't know if this will help you any further, but it's worth a try.

Do you have backups? If this file is stored in dropbox, they might have an older version. Well, if you don't have a backup, you know how useful they can be.

Comment: Thanks.  I will take a look.  I do have backups, but the backups have the same issues.  I am still interested in other methods and techniques, but I will definitely take a look at the XML to see if I can find any issues.

Comment: I performed a quick scan of the XML.  There are no obvious issues (like unmatched brackets), but with thousands of lines, it is hard to tell if there are any small issues that could be causing big problems.  In addition to content.xml, there is also a settings.xml, styles.xml, and manifest.xml.  Each one has no obvious errors, but there are thousands of small details contained in those files.

Comment: Create a new ods file. Unzip it, replace the content.xml with the broken one. Then zip it, rename it to ods and open it. See if that fixes your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and managed to recover by:

1. unzip corrupt file
2. unzip a good file
3. compared with unzipped good ods
4. found in meta.xml a difference in the following element `<meta:editing-duration>`
5. replaced it with the good one: `<meta:editing-duration>PT9M</meta:editing-duration>`
6. `zip -r filename.ods *`
7. Opened and let LibreOffice repair.

Got it back :-)

Comment: Thanks Vik!  First question: for step 3, was the good ods file just an ods file of an empty spreadsheet?

Comment: Second question: for steps 4 & 5, was your final replacement string: **<meta:editing-duration>meta:editing-durationPT9M</meta:editing-duration>**?

Comment: for step 3: It was an not empty LibreOffice Calc

Comment: for step 4&5: the corrupt one had a kind of a hash code in there.
Just realized some mistyping of the elements in my solution. 
So it looked like this:
<meta:editing-duration>PT9M</meta:editing-duration>

Comment: How did I run into the problem: ods file was open on a NAS mounted share. The laptop hibernated with open file.
Maybe need to mention: The good.ods is in the same folder location like the corrupt.ods.

Comment: Thanks for the updates Vik!  Just to clarify your first comment, you meant to write "It was not an empty LibreOffice Calc file"... correct?

Comment: Correct. The good.ods has nothing to do with the corrupt.ods
Just had some values and formulas in there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Vik.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into a similar problem with an .ods file that refused to open one of a dozen or more sheets.  It would hang the entire LibreOffice program, but only when trying to open that sheet.  What worked was to add another sheet and then the problem sheet started working. Maybe that helps here too.

Comment: Thanks. Clever tip.